# How to host and manage file uploads using NodeJS and Nginx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, nginx, web-hosting

I can't seem to get a clear answer anywhere I see this question being asked. The general question is how do you expand the space of a single server once you've filled it up with say videos and images? I'm assuming you must rent another server to continue filling it up with videos and images. Also, what sort of software stack should i be using for this?

Thanks to anybody who can answer this.

Comment: Attach a bigger hard drive?

Comment: If you're just out of storage, get a bigger drive or an additional drive.  If you're using a hosting service, pay for more storage.  If you mean to be asking something else besides this, then clarify your question because it isn't very clear what you're really trying to ask.  NGINX is perfectly fine for serving static content (if that's what you're asking).  node.js is very good for serving dynamic content and does OK with static content.

Comment: I don't think that's the solution if I want to store petabytes of data into it...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear. I know I could just put a bigger harddrive but say if I were to host a really big file hosting website. For giggles, lets say I have to store petabytes worth of videos. I don't think a single server would be able to hold that much. What trying to figure out is what sort of design pattern or method of store that much data? I also want to serve those videos to whoever requests it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cloud hosting service. Personally I use Amazon S3, but others also offer them (Rackspace, DigitalOcean, IBM, Microsoft).